# Having trouble doing random.choice, using an if statement print something when the random.choice picks a certain thing from the list

Tags: python

```
import random

allx = ["rock", "Rock", "paper", "Paper", "Scissors", "scissors"]  

rock = ["rock", "Rock"] 
paper = ["paper", "Paper"] 
scissors = ["Scissors", "scissors"]
robot = ["ROCK!", "PAPER!", "SCISSORS!"] 
while True:
    print("Let's play rock paper scissors!")
    hand = input("Choose one: ") 
    if hand not in allx:
        print("Something went wrong!") 
        continue 
    if hand in rock:
        print("You choose rock... Let's see what the computer chooses!") 
        break
    elif hand in paper: 
        print("You choose paper... Let's see what the computer chooses!")
        break
    elif hand in scissors:
        print("You choose scissors... Let's see what the computer chooses!")
        break 


choice = random.choice(robot) 

print("The robot chose " + choice)
```

now with this,  I want to see what the robot chooses from the list, comparing that to the user's choice, and seeing if they won or not. I asked a question similar to this, but it didn't have what I needed.

Comment: What output do you get, and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I deleted the whole using the input thing to my expectations, but what I usually get is nothing and what I expect is something like "The robot chooses scissors, and you chose rock. You won!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some tips to make your code shorter and easier to read

First tip: you can use the string_name.upper() or string_example.lower() to avoid creating the list with every item in lower and upper, just normalize the input of the user.

Second tip: The robot dont need another list, you cant personalize the same string of the first list adding the exclamation mark and using string.upper() again.

Thirth: You dont need to write the print sencente for every choice, you can use the .format() method of the strings

```
import random

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True:
    print("Let's play rock paper scissors!")
    human_chose = input("Choose one: ").lower()
    if human_chose in options:
        print("You choose {}... Let's see what the computer chooses!".format(human_chose))
        break
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")

robot_chose = random.choice(options)
print("The robot chose: {}".format(robot_chose.upper() + '!'))
```

Now, for compare the human_chose with the robot_chose, you can use if conditions on this way:

```
if human_chose == robot_chose: 
# the == symbols compare bot variables searching for equality
    print('You win!')
else:
    print('You lose')
```

Sorry if i over explain, i am procrastinating, and sorry for my bad english too

Correction:

```
if human_choice == 'paper':
    if robot_choice == 'rock':
        print('you win')
    elif robot_chice == 'scissors':
        print('you loss')
    else:
        print('tie')
elif human_choice == 'rock':
    if robot_choice == 'scissors':
        print('you win')
    elif robot_chice == 'paper':
        print('you loss')
    else:
        print('tie')
elif human_choice == 'scissors':
    if robot_choice == 'paper':
        print('you win')
    elif robot_chice == 'rock':
        print('you loss')
    else:
        print('tie')

# or you can do something like:

who_wins = {
    'paper': 'rock',
    'scissors': 'paper',
    'rock': 'scissors'
}

if who_wins[human_choice] == robot_chice:
    print('you win')
elif human_choice == robot_chice:
    print('tie')
else:
    print('you loss')
```

If the logic is bad you can correct it, probably the long ifs sentences will be easier to understand for you.

Comment: Wait, if the human and robot choose the same exact thing, it results in a tie, right? paper doesn't beat or win against paper

Comment: Also, thank you for your help in shortening my code, but I don't know how any of that works, and for some reason, my brain needs to understand how it works before memorizing it and doing it without me shutting down.

Comment: How you play is rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock. It's like a food web. Hope this helps